# How to load/read csv from url in flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

Hi everyone I am trying to read csv from network url from firebase storage. Url is stored in firestore I can access it easily but I am not able to read the csv using the url. I have loaded and tested the csv successfully from assets but I don't know how can I do it using network url.
If anyone knows then please let me know.

```
List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/test.csv');
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = const CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    print(csvTable);
    data = csvTable;
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Comment: What part of https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/download-files are you stuck on?

Comment: Or if you are using plain http, show your http request code that doesn't work.